# Take file upload and go to another PHP page

Tags: php, file-upload

So I have 4 pages. They are very simple.

index.php (WORKS)

```
<html>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Now upload it!">
</form>
</html>
```

upload.php (WORKS)

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

  echo 'Are you sure you want to continue saving this file';
  echo '<a href="yes.php">Yes, continue</a>
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href="no.php">No thanks</a>'
  }
?>
```

no.php (WORKS)

```
<?php
echo 'Thanks anyway';
?>
```

yes.php (ERROR)

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
      echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

      echo 'We will now save this document:';
      //Save document code
      }
    ?>
```

Output of yes:

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in /home/public_html/test/yes.php on line 2 Invalid file

We will now save this document:?
```

As you can see I never save it. But I would like to save it in the `yes.php` page. Is it still possible to retrieve that original doc that was uploaded? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the `$_FILES` var is unset when you change pages, so that wouldn't work. But you could pass the URI in `$_POST` and `fopen()` it in `yes.php`

Comment: @JamesWilliams is right. Save it to disk, and unlink() if the user wants to "not save."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploaded files are only available for a single PHP instance/request cycle.
Uploaded files are stored in the temp directory. If they're still there when the script finishes executing, PHP will delete them assuming you didn't need them.

If you want to persist the file, you'll have to move it elsewhere in the same request that the file was uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass files from a form to a different page then intended. The post values will no longer be valid. I would suggest saving the file in the upload.php to a temporary folder and from there passing it to either the yes or no page via a $_GET[] or session variable.

On the no.php page you would take that file and use

```
unlink($somefile);
```

This will delete the file from your server.

On the yes.php page I would move or copy the file. If you copy the file, I would use unlink to remove the temp file.

Comment: So, what if the user exits the page? Would the file still exist?
Because I technically haven't run anything that would delete it.

Comment: Add the temp filename to a database with a timestamp. Anything older than x minutes should be deleted. If they said yes or no, the temp file would have been deleted anyway.

Comment: @EGHDK Can go with Mr Wednesday advice or in any or all pages include a check on file age and delete after so many minutes and delete the file. I use this to have a cached version of websites.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to temporarily save the file and then pass the file information using

```
<a href="yes.php?filename=tmp_file_path">Yes, continue</a>
<a href="no.php?filename=tmp_file_path">No thanks</a>
```

Then retrieve the filename in yes.php using

```
$tmpFile = $_GET["filename"];
```

or remove it in no.php using

```
unlink($_GET["filename"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not too large, copy the file content in a session variable. The session will be preserved from one page to another.